# Does the UNGEGN release their country names localized in a format that's not a PDF?

Tags: standards, un

I'm looking for the information released by the "United Nations Group of Experts on Geographical Names" (UNGEGN), currently all I can find for the latest conference (E/CONF.105/13) is [linked on this page](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/geoinfo/UNGEGN/wg1.html),

- [E/CONF.105/13](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/geoinfo/UNGEGN/docs/11th-uncsgn-docs/E_Conf.105_13_CRP.13_15_UNGEGN%20WG%20Country%20Names%20Document.pdf) (pdf)

Is there a release that is not in PDF form so I can load it into a database? This PDF is almost impossible to parse. My parser is on hundreds of lines and there are still a slew of corner cases.

Comment: you can pull it out of here: https://github.com/Codepoints/Codepoints.net/blob/master/tools/countrynames.csv  though this dataset is from 2011, so not sure if valid enough for an answer for you.

Comment: @albert I don't think that's authoritative enough. I think they're bullshitting. That doesn't come from UNGEN, though it may come from the UN.

Comment: i figured as such; maybe you'll have better luck here: https://www.google.com/search?ei=kHspXMX2B6myggfs-4uwDg&q=UNGEGN+filetype%3Acsv&oq=UNGEGN+filetype%3Acsv&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15710.17028..17277...0.0..0.95.664.9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j33i10j33i299.K593oEasr8Q